# Meaning of "выдавить на мороз"?

Tags: phrase

I have seen somewhere they use it not in terms you could think you would do with tooth paste.. or in Siberia, related to a physiological process..

No, the example is:

> "А конкурентов выдавят на мороз"?

A Russian mafia way of doing business?

[image]
http://fritzmorgen.livejournal.com/1065051.html#cutid1

I must admit there is just one place so far where it has been used, so metaphor or a typo?

Comment: "seen somewhere" is quite broad, it would be good if you'll try to be more specific next time.

Comment: are you familiar with the English term "squeeze out"?

Comment: 'на мороз' here is just a substitute for 'outside', the phrase means 'to kick sb. out', same way 'на солнышко' is used in 'вывести за ушко да на солнышко'

Comment: @EugenePetrov exactly - it's like outside, but it's cold outside )))

Comment: btw my grandma used to say 'самых хитрых - на мороз' when we tried to cheat in something :) this shouldn't be understood literally

Comment: I think it's meant make a competitor bankrupt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than a typo, I would call it a mixed metaphor - squeezing used as a metaphor for applying whatever tactics to reduce your competitors' ability to compete, and the frost part implying that these competitors won't like the situation they'll end up in.

Comment: well, that's possible, but still quite exotic metaphor to be honest

Comment: it turns out you are right ))))

Comment: pushing out rather than squeezing

Answer (score 4):

**This turns out to be an actual usage but it's by no means an idiom.**

There's no such idiom in Russian, my guess was that this is just a typo - `выставить на мороз` (literally to put out into the frost) - which is indeed used - it's applicable both to animated and unanimated noun -  so you can equally say:

> - Я выставил на мороз жаркое - пусть хоть немного остынет
> - Я сейчас вас выставлю на мороз.

While this can be used for torture, this phrase per se does not bear any criminal or sadistic connotations. There's a phrase `выставить за дверь` - and `выставить на мороз` is constructed in a similar way - or well, the other way around.

Also, for animated nouns one can say - `выгнать на мороз` (to expel).

Also, I encourage you to use google (or other search engine) - no hidden irony, it's just that it can help immediately to see that something just does not exist:

[image]

**UPD:** Also, it's worth to mention that there's a rare term `выдавило на морозе` - it's about motor oil that sort of sipped out during cold weather, like in phrase "Выдавило масло на морозе".

**UPD:** So, when the exact quote is provided, it turns out that it's `выдавливание на мороз`. Once again, not an idiom but rather an author-specific figure of speech.

Comment: I think it also borrows form http://lurkmore.to/Выкинь_Васю_на_мороз